# Send email with standard mail client and some extras

Tags: c#, email, email-client

I need to send an e-mail with the default mail client from a .NET application. To achieve that I could use MAPI or execute the mailto command.

Either way, I can't consider all my requirements. May you know a better solution.

Email with:

- attachments
- e-mail client's default signature
- don't use the System.Web.Mail classes because no smtp server details are available.

Thank you and kind regards,
Danny

Answer (score 0):

Probably, refer to the [Programatically adding attachments to the Email through C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/SendFileToNET.aspx) to know the method of attaching some thing to the Mail. And also look the discussion done [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2007/02/24/sending-files-via-the-default-e-mail-client.aspx) to send a mail through the default mail Client

Comment: they don't consider adding the default signature of the mail client! outlook won't add the default signature to e-mail draft if it's created by the mailto command